# Alert not found in 10 seconds error, using Robot Framework RIDE

Tags: javascript, robotframework

I'm having an issue when trying to pass or handle a Javascript-based alert to accept changes during automation

Here is the code:

```
wait until element is visible    ${submit_job_btn}
wait until element is enabled    ${submit_job_btn}
mouse down    ${submit_job_btn}
mouse up    ${submit_job_btn}
sleep    5s
alert should be present    Do you want to Schedule this job    Accept    10s
wait until page contains    Job successfully scheduled
close browser.
```

I have tried the "handle alert" keyword, with the same error, note that the first submit button had different issues, where it overlapped with the page footer. so the workaround I found was to use the "mouse down"/"mouse up" to simulate clicking the button and it passed, but the alert afterward always comes back as not found.

Comment: where we can reproduce this case? is the site publicly available?

Comment: Please remove tags `alert` and `ride` because they are not applicable for this question.

Comment: @Dev, Hello, the site I am working with is not publicly available

Comment: @Helio, Thank you for pointing it out, I have removed the tags

Comment: Do you actually see the alert appear when you run the script? Is it a regular/browser one, or html based?

Comment: @TodorMinakov, The alert is HTML, and I can see the alert when doing the steps manually, but not when running the automation, there is a message on the actual alert that says "Do you want to schedule this job?", and that passes with the keywords "wait until page contains" said message, but it wont "Click"

Comment: "that passes with the keywords "wait until page contains" said message, but it wont "Click" " - well, you've just changed your question :) And if the alert is an HTML, not a browser one, the keyword `alert should be present` will not do anything. It works only on those; for the HTML ones - how would it know what you think is an alert? Universally, for any system? Just treat your as any other DOM element, and click it.